# how to change order of search viewLocation in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewengine

In my project, I have a folder called `Common`, and I want to Asp.net Mvc search the Common folder for finding Views, instead of  share folder.

In other words, the order of search location view is as follows:

```
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Common/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Common/Index.vbhtml
```

Comment: Extend the razor view engine and override the locations ?

Comment: yes i want do it

Comment: See @D-Shih 's answer. That will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create custom class inherits RazorViewEngine

```
usin System.Web.Mvc
namespace Views.Infrastructure{
public class CustomrazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngin{
    public CustomrazorViewEngine(){
        ViewLocationFormats=new string[]{
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Common/{0}.cshtml"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and in Global.asax

```
proteced void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegisteration.registerAllArea();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomrazorViewEngine());
    RoutConfig.registerRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

I suggest doing this to prevent the Confilict of other introduced Viewengines :

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution.

on `Application_Start` event to get `RazorViewEngine` by `ViewEngines.Engines` collection and update its `ViewLocationFormats`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().First();
    razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Common/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Common/{0}.vbhtml"
        };
}
```

If you want to only change the order,you can use `Concat` method to combine defalut Location and new Location.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().First();

    var newLocationPath = new string[]
    {
        "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml",
        "~/Views/Common/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Common/{0}.vbhtml"
    }.Concat(razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats);

    razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats = newLocationPath.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This will do it. Since `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` is already there by convention, you can remove the first 2 items from the array (you are doing a concat with existing items)